# iOS - Rotation with a Nav Controller

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios-4.2

It's a small but annoying issue. I'm using a navigation controller and it will not rotate. I was using the code before without a navigation controller and it was rotating beautifully. It isn't even calling "-(BOOL)shouldAutororateToInterfaceOrientation..." now so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: And yes I have "-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder" set.

Edit2: I have it calling "-(BOOL)shouldAutororateToInterfaceOrientation..." now when the App first runs and at this point the screen is rotated but then when it shows the Navcontroller sets it back to portrait mode...

Comment: Do all of your view controllers have these methods as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem with `UIWindow` propagating these events to view controllers other than the root one. If you're adding this controller directly to a `UIWindow` and it isn't the first one you've added, then add it to the root view instead.

Otherwise, you'll probably need to take a look at implementing your own rotation transformations. I've got a UIViewController subclass which does the heavy lifting for you [on github here](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQSelfRotatingViewController).

Answer (score 0):

Your controller need to have **return YES** in:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  // Overriden to allow any orientation.
  return YES;
}
```

Also if you have an UITabBarController, each controllers need that method to return YES.

Comment: I have that returning correctly, but that method isn't ever being called.